# asp mvc format timespan (mm:ss) textboxfor to work with bootstrap timepicker

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, formatting

I've read up on several posts with similar problems but still I can't get it to work properly. My problem is formating two timespan properties to mm:ss, and having them work with [this](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker) bootstrap datepicker correctly.

The model properties: (Not sure if it's correct)

```
[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:mm\:ss}")]
public TimeSpan AgentHoldoffTime { get; set; }

[DataType(DataType.Time)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = @"{0:mm\:ss}")]
public TimeSpan AgentAlertTime { get; set; }


public InteractionQueueModel() // ctor
{
     AgentAlertTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 17);
     AgentHoldoffTime = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 00);
}
```

The view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.QueueModel.AgentHoldoffTime, new { htmlAttributes = 
new { @class = "form-control timepicker-holdOffTime" } })

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.QueueModel.AgentAlertTime, new { htmlAttributes = 
new { @class = "form-control timepicker-alertTime" } })
```

JS:

```
var timePickerAlertTime = $(".timepicker-alertTime"),
    timePickerHoldOffTime = $(".timepicker-holdOffTime");

timePickerAlertTime.datetimepicker({
        format: "mm:ss",
    })
    .on("dp.change", function () {
        ...
    });

timePickerHoldOffTime.datetimepicker({
        format: "mm:ss",
    })
    .on("dp.change", function () {
        ...
    });
```

Now, when the view renders, a textbox displays `00:17` for a `time(7)` column with the value `00:00:17.0000000`. Everything seems fine, But when I submit `01:00` it's saved as `01:00:00.0000000` instead of `00:01:00.0000000`? I've probably missed something simple, but I can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should that have been `01:00` instead of `01.00`?

Comment: @ChrisPratt When I enter `01:00` ( one minute ) into the textbox the value is persisted as `01:00:00.0000000` ( one hour ). That's the problem, not sure if it's a formating issue or if it's the datepicker. Don't know about the difference in `:` vs `.`

Comment: I was referring to your question. In the last paragraph you write `01.00`. I was double-checking that that was in fact a typo, as otherwise, it would definitely be a problem.

Comment: @ChrisPratt thanks for noticing that. `01.00` was a typo, I meant to write `01:00`

Answer (score 2):

specifying the format works for me:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.AgentHoldoffTime,
    "{0:hh\\:mm}",
    new { 
       @class = "form-control",
       placeholder = "hh:mm",
})
```

this signature:

```
//
// Summary:
//     Returns a text input element.
//
// Parameters:
//   htmlHelper:
//     The HTML helper instance that this method extends.
//
//   expression:
//     An expression that identifies the object that contains the properties to display.
//
//   format:
//     A string that is used to format the input.
//
//   htmlAttributes:
//     An object that contains the HTML attributes to set for the element.
//
// Type parameters:
//   TModel:
//     The type of the model.
//
//   TProperty:
//     The type of the value.
//
// Returns:
//     An input element whose type attribute is set to "text".
public static MvcHtmlString TextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
                                this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
                                Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
                                string format,
                                object htmlAttributes);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use 'EditorFor' the Framework try to render the best HTML element for the data type, in case of TimeSpan, the best is an `<input type="time"/>`, as i understand you need handle seconds, but this input by default does not consider seconds, you'll need to "force" with attribute `step = 1`. Now if you use 'EditorFor' it does not allows you to set attributes, or at least i have not found how to do that, so changes it to 'TextBoxFor':

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.AgentHoldoffTime, new
                {
                    @class = "form-control timepicker-holdOffTime",
                    type = "time",
                    step = 1
                })
```

I Hope this help